# Converting an associative list into a BST using two different methods

Tags: haskell

Given this Tree data structure and insert function in Haskell

```
data Tree
    = Leaf
    | Node String Int Tree Tree
          deriving(Show)

insert_bst :: Tree -> String -> Int -> Tree
insert_bst Leaf ik iv = Node ik iv Leaf Leaf
insert_bst (Node k v l r) ik iv =
                if ik == k then
                     Node ik iv l r
                else if ik < k then
                     Node k v (insert_bst l ik iv) r
                else
                     Node k v l (insert_bst r ik iv)
```

What are some of the conceptual differences between these two ways of converting an associative list to a BST. One inserts items into the tree from the back, the other inserts from the front.

```
assoc_list_to_bst :: [(String, Int)] -> Tree
assoc_list_to_bst [] = Leaf
assoc_list_to_bst ((hk, hv):kvs) =
        let t0 = assoc_list_to_bst kvs
              in insert_bst t0 hk hv
```

and

```
assoc_list_to_bst :: [(String, Int)] -> Tree->Tree
assoc_list_to_bst [] tree= tree
assoc_list_to_bst ((hk, hv):kvs) tree =
        let newtree = insert_bst tree hk hv 
                in insert_bst kvs newtree
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you've answered your own question: "One inserts items into the tree from the back, the other inserts from the front.".

Comment: I'm am curious about more sophisticated differences. For example the input arguments to both functions are different, so there has to be some other difference in behaviour. There is also something to do with "tail recursion" but I am not sure what that means

Comment: These are both more specific questions, which makes them more well-suited to SO. I suggest you include them in your question and possibly elaborate a little bit (in particular, if you don't know what 'tail recursion' means, there is very little you can get from someone explaining to you what the role of tail recursion here is - you should get a basic understanding first and then ask a specific question about anything you misunderstand).